# why is the unit test not passed?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have such a test:

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            List<int> gameboard = new List<int> {
                -1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,
                0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,
                -1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
                1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1

            };
            int x = 5;
            int y = 1;
            List<List<int>> expected = new List<List<int>> {
                new List<int>(){
                -1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,
                0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,
                -1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,
                1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1
                }
            };
            var calc = new Checkers.PieceMovment();
            List<List<int>> actual = calc.MoveRightForward(gameboard, x, y);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

In expected, I enter what I previously received in the console. Because I know it's the right value. And i get this message:
failed Assert.AreEqual. Expected: <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]>. Actually: <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]>.

And I don't understand what the problem is . . .

Comment: Don't use "Assert.AreEqual" on collections, use CollectionAssert.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks , but now i get CollectionAssert failed.AreEqual. (The element at index 0 does not match.) and I still don't understand what the reason is. Since the console and expected have the same values.

Comment: It may be that you have to write the comparison yourself, as it's probably now just moving the problem you had with Assert.AreEqual to the first element insted.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how do I do this? I just wasn't familiar with unit tests before..

Comment: You do realize and are aware of that `gameboard` and the result of your method under test are different types (`List<int>` vs `List<List<int>>`) ? I woud expect a gameboard and the mutation of it to be the same types. On a `List<int>` a CollectionAssert would probably work.

Comment: @Fildor  I pass the gameboard to a method that returns List<List<int>>

Comment: Exactly. That's surprising to me.

Comment: @Fildor all right. some pieces may have several moves to the right up. (I mean the queen in checkers) , so i use list<list<int>>

Answer (score 1):

When you are using collection, use [CollectionAssert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2022)

`Assert.AreEqual(List<int>, List<int>)` checks the reference of list 1 and list 2, so it returns false in your case where lists have different references.

CollectionAssert enumerates each item and asserts if they are equal or not.

TL/DR: Use the following code.

```
 CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```